# drag and drop element to any location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two issues,

1. I am able to move div element once dropped in RED div, but if I try to reposition the element code messes up.
2. I want to save position X/Y & ID of div moved to RED Div on SAVE button Click.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({ cursor: "crosshair", revert: "invalid"});
$("#drop").droppable({ accept: ".draggable", 
           drop: function(event, ui) {
                    console.log("drop");
                   $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
             var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).detach().css({}).appendTo(droppedOn);      
                }, 
          over: function(event, elem) {
                  $(this).addClass("over");
                   console.log("over");
          }
                ,
                  out: function(event, elem) {
                    $(this).removeClass("over");
                  }
                     });
$("#drop").sortable();

$("#origin").droppable({ accept: ".draggable", drop: function(event, ui) {
                    console.log("drop");
                   $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
             var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);      
             
             
                }});
$(".save").click(function() {
    getCordinates();
});
function getCordinates(){
    var c = document.getElementById("drop").children.length;
  alert(c);
}
```

Fiddler link for the code: [Code Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/39khs/82/)

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "you try reposition the element"?

Comment: @JoseRojas if you see, when you drag element in RED Div, the position is not that of where mouse points. I would like to place the element where mouse points.

Comment: what you say is not happening to me, the element always has the cursor position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first point I could not replicate it, regarding to the second point you can obtain the id in the event drop of your div (`#origin` or `#drop`) like this:

```
$(ui.draggable).attr("id")
```

and the X and Y Position of the img has been dropped you can obtain this way:

```
//position X
$(ui.draggable).offset().left
//Position Y
$(ui.draggable).offset().top
```